# How to make an array containing a duplicate of an array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I couldn't find a way to build an array such as

```
[  [1,2,3] , [1,2,3] , [1,2,3] , [1,2,3] , [1,2,3]  ]
```

given `[1,2,3]` and the number `5`. I guess there are some kind of operators on arrays, such as `product` of `mult`, but none in the [doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-product) does it. Please tell me. I missed something very simple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Array.new(5, [1, 2, 3])` **or** `Array.new(5) { [1, 2, 3] }`

`Array.new(size, default_object)` creates an array with an initial size, filled with the default object you specify. Keep in mind that if you mutate **any** of the nested arrays, you'll mutate **all** of them, since **each element is a reference to the same object**.

```
array = Array.new(5, [1, 2, 3])
array.first << 4
array # => [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

`Array.new(size) { default_object }` lets you create an array with **separate objects**.

```
array = Array.new(5) { [1, 2, 3] }
array.first << 4
array #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Look up at the very top of [the page you linked to](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html), under the section entitled "Creating Arrays" for some more ways to create arrays.

Comment: Hum, totally missed this... Thanks ! :)

Comment: I don't often look at the top of the doc pages, either. Count it as a lesson learned for both of us :)

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use:

```
[[1, 2, 3]] * 5 
# => [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

The documentation for [Array.*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-2A) says:

> ...returns a new array built by concatenating the `int` copies of self.

Typically we'd want to create a repeating single-level array:

```
[1, 2, 3] * 2 
# => [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

but there's nothing to say we can't use a sub-array like I did above.

---

> It looks like mutating one of the subarrays mutates all of them, but that may be what someone wants.

It's like `Array.new(5, [1,2,3])`:

```
foo = [[1, 2, 3]] * 2
foo[0][0] = 4
foo # => [[4, 2, 3], [4, 2, 3]]

foo = Array.new(2, [1,2,3])
foo[0][0] = 4
foo # => [[4, 2, 3], [4, 2, 3]]
```

A work-around, if that's not the behavior wanted is:

```
foo = ([[1, 2, 3]] * 2).map { |a| [*a] }
foo[0][0] = 4
foo # => [[4, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

But, at that point it's not as convenient, so I'd use the default `Array.new(n) {…}` behavior.

Comment: I like this approach, too. It looks like mutating one of the subarrays mutates all of them, but that may be what someone wants.